# Amazon Redshift Invalid operation: column notation .id applied to type character, which is not a composite type; Spring Data JPA

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift, composite-types

I am getting an error when trying to pull from an Amazon Redshift DB and can't figure out how to fix it.

Error:

```
com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: 
    column notation .id applied to type character, which is not a composite type;
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:redshift://mydb.blah.region.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev?currentSchema=myschema

spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ContactController {
        
    private RedshiftRepo repo;
    
    @Autowired
    public ContactController(RedshiftRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/get")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> getTest(){
        
        List<Contact> list = repo.findAll();        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Contact>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getByEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Contact>> getByEmail(@RequestParam String email){
        
        List<Contact> list = repo.getContactByEmail(email);         
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Contact>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

RedshiftRepo:

```
@Repository
public interface RedshiftRepo extends JpaRepository<Contact, Integer>{
    
    @Query("select id, firstname, lastname, accountid from Contact c where c.email = ?1")
    public Contact getContactByEmail(String email);
    
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="user")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String firstname;
    
    private String lastname;
    
    private String accountid;

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.contactAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>pocContactAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pocContactAPI</name>
    <description>Contact Getter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-redshift</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.999</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.41.1065</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>redshift</id>
            <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I try to GET localhost:8080/get:

```
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.firstname,c1_0.lastname,c1_0.accountid from user c1_0

com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: 
    column notation .id applied to type character, which is not a composite type;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have the same error if you change the table name in your definition `@Table(name ="user")` from user to something else.. sometimes the above error occurs if the name clashes with a system table name..

Comment: @Neeraj That might have worked, but now I am getting access issues to a db I have access to...  However, staying on topic, How do I get past the name issue and still access a table called "user"?

Comment: can you try specifying the schema in the JPA annotation - `@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema="test")`?

Comment: @Neeraj I just tried that again but same error as the original post

Comment: In that case, you should see why the user table already exists.. if it is a system table you should pick a different name or if someone else created it you can see if it can be dropped.. You can also pick a table name e.g. contact which is inline with your Java entity..

Comment: Thank you but I don't think the DBA will want me to tell them to change their tables haha. But I will reach out to them to see how they have been accessing it while it has this name. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

*(It is my understanding that this first step has already been completed by you, however I am including it for others as well.)*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
    <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.41.1065</version>
</dependency>
```

This will allow you to use the Redshift JDBC driver. You can find more information on this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html

You also need to specify the Redshift driver in your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
```

You can find more information on this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

After making these changes, I was able to run your application and get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "accountid": "1"
    }
]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did have the first one and I added the second one, but I am still getting the same error. Could there be something else that I am forgetting? Thanks

Comment: Very interesting, are you able to share a link to the repo or is the codebase private?

Comment: Unfortunately the codebase is private (for work)

Comment: Ok no worries. I am going to play around with it a bit more and see if I can recreate the error another way.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good to know for knowledge sake and for anyone that finds this in the future, but my work just changed which schema/tables I will be working with and I'm not getting this issue when accessing them. It may be the fact that "user" may be a system table or is otherwise unusable as @Neeraj posted above. Thanks again for your help!